# pad prefresh to any window instead of stdscr?

Tags: c, ncurses

Is there a way I can have a pad refresh to any window instead of (presumably) `stdscr`?  I suppose I could temporarily change `stdscr` every time I want to draw the pad, but that seems a little silly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just happened to have exactly same need for such function and I was more lucky: Try `copywin` function, it should do what you need. However - unlike `prefresh` - it doesn't do the refresh - you have to refresh the destination window yourself to display copied data.

http://nfosolutions.com/doc_link/C/a_doc_lib/libs/basetrf2/copywin.htm